# Missing letter identification in bibliography for two papers with same author and year. (Natbib+BibTex+makebst)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib, custom-bib

I've made a custom `.bst` file, using `makebst`. When using `Natbib`, I get for two papers in the same year and author, a letter identifying the two papers as "a" and "b" in the citation. Sadly, no letter is added in the bibliography. If I change my `bibliographystyle` to `plainnat`, I see the letters. Hope someone can help me...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Hansen2015a,
author = {Hansen, Jens},
title = {Title One},
year = {2015}
}
@misc{Hansen2015b,
author = {Hansen, Jens},
title = {Title Two},
year = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\citep{Hansen2015a} and~\citep{Hansen2015b} or \citep{Hansen2015a,Hansen2015b}.
\bibliographystyle{bibstyle}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[BST file](https://db.tt/NUW5iXqF)

Custom bst-style:

[image: bibstyle]

PlainNat Style:

[image: plainnat]

Comment: Oh boy it has been years since I was using makebst the last time. I am sure that it was asking you as one of the first questions which bib-compiler you are using, and natbib was to be declared as 'some non-standard system' or so. Did you remember to choose that option, otherwise using natbib might misinterpret the bst.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to run the `makebst` again. It helped me locating the missing code in the bst-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to `extra.label`, which was missing in the original bst-file. Running the `makebst` again and copying the code-snip from the new bst-file works for me now.

Old code:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  month "month" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year"  bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
}
```

New bst-code for FUNCTION {format.date}

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  month "month" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    {
      " " * swap$
    }
  if$
  *
  extra.label *
  before.all 'output.state :=
  ", " swap$ *
}
```